# Express read body and debug output

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm developing this node application on a windows machine.

Here is my `index.js`:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    httpDebug = require('debug')('http'),
    name = "realtime";

var db = { users: [{name: 'callum'},{name:'chris'}] };

/*--- IMPORTANT STUFF ---*/

httpDebug('booting %s', name);

/*------------------------*/

app.use('/', express.static('website'));

app.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    httpDebug(req.method + ' ' + req.url);

    res.send(db.users);
});
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
    httpDebug(req.method + ' ' + req.url);
});
```

The `debug` library does not seem to send debugging output to the console....

Answer (score 0):

You need to run inedx.js with `DEBUG` variable, like this:

```
$ DEBUG=http node index.js
```

See the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug

E.g. if you have multiple debug labels, like `api`, `http`, `tests`, and you only want to show `api` and `http`, you'll do

```
$ DEBUG=api,http node index.js
```

Comment: what package can I use to avoid having to do that?!

Comment: I really don't like having to do that just in order to get debugging output. I should be able to do it via configuration in my app

Comment: Anyways I did try that and it didn't work, still no output

Comment: Maybe [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) will help you or If you only want to debug HTTP requests, check out [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan)

Comment: @CallumLinington environment variable *are* configuration btw

Comment: I followed the debug documentation on setting DEBUG on windows using the * as the value.

Comment: @Bergi setting the windows environment variables is far to "heavy" for a small app to be doing, it just shouldn't be necessary

Comment: yeah, i'll probably move to using winston, it has a better feel to me

Comment: Glad I helped you :)

Comment: @CallumLinington They're mostly supposed to be set in the console session (like shown in the answer), not in the windows settings

Comment: @Bergi it's weird, because reading the docs eludes to doing it this way...